# Modifying a shell variable with regex (bash)

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, string, variable-substitution

I have a shell variable for example. a="big little man". How do I use regex in bash print out the variable with only the middle word capitalized? (big LITTLE man)

I can do it by separating the variable into 3 variables and then expanding them in echo. For eg `first=${a%* }`, etc. But how do I do it in one single go with one regex?

Is it possible to do it in a single line? Using the capitalize operators (^)

Comment: I can do it by separating the string into 3 different variables and then echoing it together with the mid variable capitalized. I wanted to know if I can do it in one go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**sed**

Assuming you're using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)/\1 \U\2\E \3/' <<< 'big little man'
big LITTLE man
```

This command makes use of the [GNU specific sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) `\U` and `\E` which turn the subsequent characters into upper case and cancel case conversion respectively.

**awk**

While not operating on regular expressions, `awk` provides another convenient way to capitalize a single word:

```
$ awk '{print($1, toupper($2), $3)}' <<< 'big little man'
big LITTLE man
```

**bash**

Although Bash on its own does not have regular expression based conversions, you can still achieve partial capitalization by treating your string as an array, e.g.

```
$ (read -a words; echo "${words[0]} ${words[1]^^} ${words[2]}") <<< 'big little man'
big LITTLE man
```

Here `^^` converts the second element of our array (i.e. the second word) to upper case. The feature was introduced in Bash 4.

Answer (score 5):

As requested, doing it in `bash` on a single line using `${variable^^}`:

```
$ a="big little man"
$ [[ "$a" =~ ^([^ ]+)\ ([^ ]+)\ (.*) ]] && a="${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]^^} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
$ echo "$a"
big LITTLE man
```

This matches the regular expression `([^ ]+)\ ([^ ]+)\ (.*)` against the string in `$a`.  If it matches, then it contains three substrings separated by spaces.  The first and second substring will be any string not containing a space, and the third substring will be the remaining bit of the string.

If the expression matches, the `$a` value is rewritten with the second substring in upper case.

This assumes that the original string starts with a non-space character.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do it with `bash` expansion operators in one go. You could with `zsh`'s:

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#m)

b=${a/(#m) * /${(U)MATCH}}
```

or:

```
b=${(S)a/(#b)(*) (*) (*)/$match[1] ${(U)match[2]} $match[3]}
```

Where:

- `(#m)` causes the matched string to be available in `$MATCH`
- `(#b)` enables back-references
- `${(U)var}` (also `$var:u`) turns to upper case (predates `bash`'s `${var^^pattern}` by decades).
- `(S)` turns on non-greedy matching.

Comment: Which bash version do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus Stéphane is using `zsh`, not `bash`.